# Julia - Equivalent of python `pop`. Remove elements from array using boolean array and return them

Tags: julia

Is there an equivalent to Python's `pop`? I have an array `x` and a boolean array `flag` of the same length. I would like to extract `x[flag]` and be able to store it in a variable `x_flagged` while at the same time remove them in place from `x`.

```
x = rand(1:5, 100)
flag = x .> 2
x_flagged = some_function!(x, flag)   # Now x would be equal to x[x .<= 2]
```

Comment: Btw there is `pop!` function which returns and removes element from collection. https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/collections/#Base.pop!-Tuple{Any,%20Any,%20Any}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `splice!` with a bit of help from `findall`:

```
julia> x_flagged = splice!(x, findall(flag))
59-element Vector{Int64}:
...
julia> size(x)
(41,)
```

> `splice!(a::Vector, indices, [replacement]) -> items`
> Remove items at specified indices, and return a collection containing the removed items.

Answer (score 2):

Try this one using `deleteat!`

```
julia> function pop_r!(list, y) t = list[y]; deleteat!( list, y ); t end

julia> x = rand(1:5, 100)
100-element Vector{Int64}

julia> flag = x .> 2
100-element BitVector

julia> pop_r!( x, flag )
60-element Vector{Int64}

julia> x
40-element Vector{Int64}
```